# Why I can't append a list to csv as a new row?

Tags: csv, class

so I'm getting this error:

```
self.list_of_employees.write(new_employee_data)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

and I don't understand what's the problem with my code:

```
def add_employee(self, new_employee):
    new_employee_data = [new_employee.employee_id, new_employee.name, new_employee.phone, new_employee.age]
    with open(self.list_of_employees, 'r+') as file1:
        existing_lines = csv.reader(file1)
        for row in existing_lines:
            if new_employee_data in row:
                print("Sorry, the employee is already exist.")
                return
        self.list_of_employees.write(new_employee_data)
```

I'd be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function appears to be part of a larger class. Is that correct? The error message indicates `self.list_of_employees` a string, which would be consistent with the `open()` use. Python strings don't have a `.write()` method.

The `file1` is a file handle, which is what the `.write()` is expecting:

```
def add_employee(self, new_employee):
    new_employee_data = [new_employee.employee_id, new_employee.name, new_employee.phone, new_employee.age]
    with open(self.list_of_employees, 'r+') as file1:
        existing_lines = csv.reader(file1)
        for row in existing_lines:
            if new_employee_data in row:
                print("Sorry, the employee is already exist.")
                return
        file1.write(new_employee_data)
```

Comment: Oh I see, yes self.list_of_employees refers the file path as a string, so I should refer the write to the data inside the file. Thanks!

Comment: @Rose - If my response addressed your issue, please mark the answer as the accepted solution.